# ¿Como puedo obtener un valor agrupando por una columna y filtrado por un status?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quiero obtener el valor de una columna (archivo) que se agrupa por ella misma solo si el estatus de todos los registros pertenecientes a esa agrupación no tiene nada diferente a 0. Ejemplo de datos:

```
id status archivo
 1   0    file1
 2   0    file2
 3   1    file1
 4   0    file2
 5   0    file3
 6   0    file3
```

el objetivo es obtener algo así:

```
archivo
file2
file3
```

Esto por que el nombre(`file1`) tiene dentro de sus registros agrupados un `status = 1`, solo (`file2 & file3`) cumplen con el requisito que en la agrupacion de sus registros no tienen ningun registro que tenga status diferente a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un conteo de todos y de los ceros y comparar si hay diferencias, por ejemplo:

```
 SELECT archivo FROM 
 (
 SELECT archivo,count(*) FILTER (WHERE status=0) ceros,
 count(*)  todos
 FROM t   GROUP BY 1
 ) AS sub 
 WHERE sub.ceros=sub.todos;

archivo 
---------
 file2
 file3
```